# How to copy files from any build sub folder with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How can I define a variable path reference to copy all zip files from build folder into a target folder?

```
task export(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn build
  from ('sub-projects/**/build') {
    include '**/*.zip'
  }
  into 'target-folder' }
```

There is an issue from Gradle:
Could not normalize path for file `'C:\checkout\file\path\to\project\sub-projects\**\build'`.

I'm using Gradle Version 2.2.1 at Windows7.

Comment: Does that not work? What's the error? It sounds like you want `'target-folder'` to be a variable, based on what? What version of gradle?

Comment: @Tony: I update my question. Thank's for your hint!

Comment: Gradle can't normalize the variable path notation with two stars in between example path name 'sub-projects' and build path folder. The two stars should reflect all sub project name like 'sub-projects/project-name-A/build', 'sub-projects/project-name-B/build', 'sub-projects/project-name-{n}/build'.

Comment: According to [this forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unable-to-use-regex-in-copy-task/4893) you cannot use wildcards in a `from` selector.